# What is the word for "leaving something running, but not changing/touching it"

Tags: word-request

Like some system or software, if you decide to make no more changes to it and just leave it alone, but still operationing, what is that called?

Comment: What part of speech are you looking for? Verb, noun, adjective, adverb…?

Comment: I'd call it stable, but that describes the state of the thing more than the thing.

Answer (score 1):

You probably look for [**unattended**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unattended):

> **unattended** (adj.) = not being watched or taken care of:
>
> - Please do not leave your luggage **unattended**.
> - According to the report, most accidents occur when young children are left **unattended** in the home.